# How to migrate from existing system to bitnami version

Tags: mongodb, bitnami, migrate, openedx

I'm trying to migrate course content from existing system to bitnami version

The existing system has different schema with bitnami version (MongoDB)

Is there anyway to migrate the course content from existing system to bitnami version?

- The existing system schema:

  fs.chunks
  fs.files
  modulestore.active_versions
  modulestore.definitions
  modulestore.structures (course content location)
- The bitnami system schema:

  fs.chunks
  fs.files
  modulestore

Please give some advice!

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/edx/edx-platform/wiki/Split:-the-versioning,-structure-saving-DAO to understand how OpenEDX saves content into MongoDB.

Use the import/export procedure described here http://edx.readthedocs.io/projects/edx-partner-course-staff/en/latest/releasing_course/export_import_course.html#export-a-course